# What determines time spent dead in League of Legends?

Tags: league-of-legends

I've just started playing League of Legends, so I'm getting plenty of first hand experience with being dead. However, I haven't figured out what determines the length of time I spend in limbo, does anyone know the time amounts and/or the formula to determine how much time my X number death will cost me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Champion level** and **time spent in the game** are the main factors - longer games = longer death timers; higher level = longer death timers.

On Summoner's Rift time spent dead scales from **12-50 seconds** as [Wiki says](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Death#Death_timer).

There isn't a calculated formula for champion death time, at least not one known by the players.

There are some ways to reduce this time. Utility tier one mastery [**Good Hands**](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Good_Hands) reduces death time by 4% / 7% / 10%. Each **[Quintessence of Revival](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_runes#Revival)** reducse death time by 5%. There is also the summoner spell [**Revive**](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Revive) which instantly revives your champion.

Different maps have different death timers as well. From shortest to longest:

1. Dominion
2. Proving Grounds
3. Twisted Treeline (3v3 map)
4. Summoner's Rift (5v5 map)

Comment: Karthus' passive no longer reduces death time :(

Comment: @tzenes - the way I understand it, for a while Karthus' passive was 'double-counting' time spent dead, because they had given Karthus less death time initially, and then they were later able to start the death timer as soon as his passive triggered. Once this happened, they removed the innate lower death time so that it was once again only counted once.

Comment: I guess it depends on your perspective.  Either it gives him extra life after death (in which case it doesn't count the death timer and he has a reduced dead time) or it allows him to act while dead (in which case it does count the death timer and he does not have reduced time dead).

Comment: @Tzenes - for a while he had both.

Comment: I'm aware, that's why I said his passive no longer reduces death time